# How Can I use a custom authorizer in alb

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer, lambda-authorizer

I would like to create ECS clusters and an application load balancer as below

[image]

I wanted to implement lambda authorizer in alb as like as api gateway. but it didn't support lambda authorizer. Only supports AWS cognito and OIDC.

So I was thinking about to add api gateway with lambda authorizer between alb and private subnets. but It did seem like a bad way.

How Can I find a good way? Please help me.